# Achieving Notifications after killing app similar to WhatsApp

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, pushkit

We are trying to achieve a notification feature similar to WhatsApp(iOS version) notification handling,  even after killing WhatsApp explicitly- notification message appears on top chat with new message with message count – This can be achieved thru VOIP Push.

Would like to understand whether financial App can use VOIP and whether this will not cause a rejection of the app.

Comment: If you app does not supply any VOIP to the user you can not use VOIP push. But you can use silent push notification to trigger a fetch. [Configuring a Silent Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app will get rejected with the reason as,

> **2.16: Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.** 
>   We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include functionality that requires that mode to run persistently.

Your app has to support VOIP if you intend to use VOIP push.

**Note that if you just want to show badge count without showing notification, then it can be achieved through silent notification.**

iOS shows badge count irrespective of application running state, i.e. even if your app is explicitly killed, on receive of silent notification, badge count will be reflected. Note that, app is not waken up if it is killed.

Your payload should be,

```
{
"aps" : 
      { "content-available" : 1
        "badge" : 5
      }
}
```

Check out some good tutorials on Silent Push Notifications

https://blog.layer.com/how-we-leverage-ios-push-notifications/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial